# How to resume a failed spring batch job if the step execution context is stored as empty in BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT table?

Tags: spring-batch

The DB restart happened during the execution of a spring batch job and it got stuck at the 'Started' state. I marked the job as failed and tried resuming the same. Instead of resuming the failed job it created a new instance and executed the job from the beginning. During analysis, I found that due to the abrupt restart of the DB, the step context of the job was not stored in the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT table and hence it triggered a new instance instead of resuming the failed one.
Is there a way to resume a failed batch job if the step context is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you cannot restart the job. Without restart data, Spring Batch cannot restart the same job instance.